# Double light switch with one red and three black wires

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m in the middle of a diy kitchen remodel on an older home.  In the beginning of the remodel I had some cabinetry fall and break a double light switch.  One switch controlled a light above the sink.  The other switch controlled an outlet below the sink for the garbage disposal. The 2nd outlet was always on and used for the dishwasher.  I’m trying to install a new switch and think I got my wires mixed up.  There are three black wires and one red wire.  I attached them the same way they had been (or so I thought). Red wire on black screw top left, and the black wires on the other black screw and two brass screws.  Now one outlet works when one of the switches is turned on.  The other outlet has no power, and the other outlet doesn’t send power to light.  Currently there is no light installed, just wires.  But I don’t get any reading from my voltage detector.  From what I’ve read, the black and red wire that are paired together should be connected to the brass screws.  They both go to the outlet below the sink.  I tried connecting them like that, on the brass screws and was the same outcome.  The brass clip connecting the black wires has been broken.  I figured I’d try asking online before calling an electrician.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a few pictures of the switch box and outlet box?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  Tried a new switch without breaking the brass tab connecting the black screws and it works perfectly.